# Stiffness of linear systems of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

What would be the relative stiffness of the following linear systems of ODEs? I understand that the first case has two eigenvalues with negative real parts, and is therefore stiff. The eigenvalues for the second system have no negative real parts, and it is therefore not stiff. The third I am having trouble with as one of the eigenvalues is equal to zero. What does this mean in terms of stiffness?

1) [ [-2, 1], [1, -2] ]

2) [ [0, 1], [-1, 0] ]

3) [ [-10^3, 1], [1, -10^(-3)] ]

Answer (score 3):

No, your reasoning for stiffness is not correct. In general, stiffness is a fuzzy concept. For the general idea, consider a situation where you have some components that converge very fast to some (transient) equilibrium, and some slower components. Then with some numerical methods, especially explicit methods, the fast components force a very small step size to avoid sharply zigzagging behavior, even as they move now slowly along the equilibrium position.

Besides the increased computational effort, a small step size also causes more accumulation of floating point rounding noise, giving a lower bound on acceptable step sizes. This can shrink the working range, where the local error behaves like the order of the method predicts, to an unworkable small size. As said, this happens less to implicit methods with their larger stability region.

The sign of the eigenvalues is only interesting in that for the convergence of a component you need a negative real part in the eigenvalues corresponding to this component.